# Delete specific elements within a json string of postgres table

Tags: json, postgresql, openstreetmap

I have an OSM table (in a postgres database) of all the countries in the world with the column "tags" in a json text format giving a lot of different info about the given country:

```
psql/mydb# \d osm_country
       Column       |            Type             
--------------------+-------------------
 id                 | integer            
 name               | text                    
 tags               | text
```

The column "tags" has different types of info such as "flag", "note", "official_name", ""ISO3166-1:numeric", ... and a very high number of "name:XX" with the name of the given country in the XX language. For example for the row "France" I have in the "tags" column:

```
{ "flag":"http://www.flags/france.jpeg", "note":"blabla", "iso2":"FR",
"name:fr": "France", "name:es": "Francia", "name:en": "France"
"name:af": "Frankryk", "name:ak": "Frɛnkyeman", "name:ast": "Francia",
"name:am": "ፈረንሣይ", "name:an": "Francia", "name:ar": "فرنسا",
"name:ja": "フランス", "name:zh": "法國", "name:zu": "IFulansi",
....
"ISO3166-1:numeric": "250","osm_changeset": "47737436}
```

And there is a huge amount of different languages here. I would like to keep  just a few specific name:XX (french, english, spanish, ...) and all the different tags other than "name:XX" (flag, note, iso2, ....). Note: the others flags than name:XX change from a country to another, for example some have the "flag" tag and some others don't.

I have done this but with a complex set of instructions using cursors and temp tables, but I'm pretty sure I don't know how to handle the json in the good way. Do you know is there is a way to perform this by a unique query?

Thanks, Thomas

Comment: Why you have `tags` with type `text` in the first place when you store JSON document? If you can update your `tags` text type e.g. to `jsonb` type then it's easy to do all kinds of magic with JSON documents (see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) :)

Comment: To delete the Japanese name: `tags::jsonb - 'name:ja'`

Comment: It's a direct download from Open Street Map. I just altered the column to make it a jsonb, thanks for the tip. I'll now browse your link to see if I can find what I need.

Comment: actualy I need more some thing like a "not in" than the " - ", indeed, I just want to keep a few languages among a few hundreds